# Resizing Custom tablevVewCell for different devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have an iOS app with a tableview and custom tableview cell.

My tableview has fixed size constraints on both left and right sides so that it gets wider if I switch to a device with a larger screen.

When I change devices in the simulator I would like my custom tableview cell to stretch to fill the new tableview.

As it stands, when I switch to the 6 plus size, I am getting my originally sized cell with a white space at the end to fill the remaining space.

Any thoughts as to how to resize the custom cell appropriately?
(Alternatively, is there any way to change the white space at the end to transparent?)

Comment: If you are doing it programatically, please try this in your custom cell

'[self setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];'

If you are doing it with .xib,

please activate `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth` auto resizing mask.

Comment: What constraints have you created for the TableView?

Comment: Where would I activate UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth? Is there a box to check in interface builder?

Comment: Are you using autolayout (hint: you should)? What happens to the row separator (gray line)? Does it stretch, or does it stay the original width?

Answer (score 0):

you can give height of a cell in heightforRowatIndexPAth

#define IS_IPHONE_6Plus                 ((UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) && ([[UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds].size.height ==736.0f))

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

if (IS_IPHONE_6Plus)

{

//Return 6plus height

}

else

{

```
//  Height
```

}

Answer (score 0):

So looking at your recent comment, I think you do have custom cell with .xib.
To set `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth` mask - Click on your .xib file, then in right pane, in the 5th option you can see we can set frame related options.
There you can set autoresizing mask for your custom cell.

[image]

Likewise, top line              - UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin

```
     left line              - UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin

     bottom line            - UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin

     right line             - UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin

     middle horizontal line - UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth

     middle vertical line   - UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight
```

You can select the options, and can check the behavior of your object, how it will response [position on superview of your object] to different sizes of your superview.